# Проблема с import tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Если запустить так:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

то все работает.
А если так:

```
import tkinter
root = Tk()
```

то пишет что переменная Tk не определена. Почему?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данное выражение импортирует **все модули** из библиотеки `tkinter`, поэтому класс `Tk` появляется в области видимости.

```
from tkinter import *
```

А здесь вы импортируете лишь сам модуль, а для доступа к его содержимому надо явно указать, откуда это содержимое.

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
```